# Three.js + imported model : how to display edge lines?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I load a .js model exported from 3DSMAX via convert_obj_three.py and display it using objects 'solid color'.

```
loader.load( 'try.js', function ( geometry, materials )
{
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    scene.add( mesh );
});
```

The render mode is basic and descriptive (there is no material in this example). Now I'm trying to add edges ('hidden lines' mode) to get [this kind of render (image from 3DSMAX)](http://hpics.li/5015a60).

The aim would be to add colored edges to the MeshFaceMaterial (lines color would be the same object 'solid color' than faces).

I've notice that we can append materials [(like in this stemkoski example)](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Wireframe.html) but not been able to do that with my materials json, how would you do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your geometry is instanceof THREE.Geometry and not instanceof THREE.BufferGeometry (wireframe is not implemented for BufferGeometry) then you can achieve the effect you want by adding this line to your scene (in addition to the one you have):

```
scene.add (new THREE.Mesh (geometry,
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({ color: 0x00ffff, wireframe: true })));
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I suppose I could iterate through materials json to get each object's color .. However I have 2 remarks :  1- Wireframe divides polygonal geometries into 3 or 4 sides faces (even if it's plane) as you can see [on this image](http://hpics.li/4520096). Is it the normal behaviour for wireframe ?   2- This new line is duplicating geometry too, so in the case of heavy model there's no way to append only the new material just like into the example I linked ?

Comment: n-sided polygonal geometries are always converted to triangles or 4-sided polygons. It has nothing to do with wireframe mode.

Comment: Yes, I meant that in 3D modelers edges between coplanar faces are not displayed. I suppose this display mode is not implemented (harm). Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Sorry to come back but that's just to clarify this point : .OBJ geometries can be defined as polygonals, but they are not rendered correctly in three.js ([in this image I've made a test with polygonal export from 3DSMAX](http://hpics.li/3fee2d5)).
Do we have to consider that as a normal limitation or as an issue ?
In the first case do you think I could make a request for a new 'hidden line' (so called in 3D Modelers) render mode that doesn't display edges between coplanar faces ?

Comment: For the first issue you should create a new question so more people can read it, as I am not sure about the limitations of the OBJMTLLoader. As per the hidden line you can request it at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues

Comment: Ok. It seems that export from 3DSMAX has to be done as Triangles faces (Quads mode makes some other troubles), I'll report my tests. Thanks

Comment: Now in Q2 2015, you may look into using the EdgesHelper http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/EdgesHelper from MrDoob.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, many thanks ! you should post this as an answer.